# CSS background-image is overflowing

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

I have a background that I'm trying to cover with a gradient but the gradient isn't long enough or something like that

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(18, 16, 32, 0.8), rgba(20, 28, 58, 1)) no-repeat, url("imgs/Untitled-1.png") no-repeat;
    background-color: rgb(20, 28, 58);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent horizontal scroll */
}
```

[image: Background image overflowing]

I tried changing `background-position` but nothing helps

Comment: It would be better if you using [Code Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) for your question

Answer (score 0):

with height adjustment: 100%; The gradient extends to cover the entire viewport height .

```
body
 {
  ....

  height:100%;
 }
```